# ASIHTTPRequest timeout not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

The code is the following, however I can't figure out why it's not timing out even after 10 seconds has passed. Any idea?

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:sourceURL];
                        [request setTimeOutSeconds:5.0];
                        [request setDelegate:self];
                        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
                            //some code
                        }];

                        [request setFailedBlock:^{
                            //some code

                        }];


                        self.currentRequest_ = request;
                        [self.currentRequest_ startAsynchronous];


    - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
        NSLog(@"FAILED");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the request completed successfully then?

Other possibility is that there was data being received at least every 5 seconds, but the full data has not yet been received. ASI will only timeout if nothing is received for the timeout period, so if data is constantly arrived the request won't time out.

Comment: aha...I think that's what happened.. the data is pulled constantly, it's just that it's slow.. is there a way then to stop ignoring whether data was received or not?

Comment: Nothing built into ASIHTTPRequest. You could just setup an NSTimer yourself, that's probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you call `-[ ASIHTTPRequest startAsynchronous]`... Instead add the request (which is a subclass of `NSOperation`) to a `ASINetworkQueue` (a subclass of `NSOperationQueue`). HTH

Comment: Also, `ASINetworkQueue` starts in the paused state, so after you add your request, be sure to call `-[ASINetworkQueue go]`. You might have to look up what the method is called.. I forget.